# How to find out if a rendering is used in any page

Tags: presentation

Using Sitecore 10.1.3

We have an existing application which uses both SXA default & custom renderings.  There are 100+ renderings and many are not in use any more.

For each rendering, I would check `Navigate > Links`. For some, I could see the page item reference but some refer to `.../Presentation/Available renderings`.

And some references are `Partial Designs`.

So, it is challenging to find out which renderings are actually being used in page items.

Is there a quick way to find out, like a Powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to know How many times is each rendering used for a specific website. You can use the below Powershell Script with more information for each rendering.

1. Open PowerShell ISE (You can found this in /sitecore/shell/  menu, Development Tools, PowerShell ISE
2. Copy past the script below.
3. Save as  "How many times is each rendering used for a specific website"  below Script Library/SPE/Reporting/Content Reports/Reports/Solution Audit

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        How many times is each rendering used in your solution?
         
    .NOTES
        copy from www.stockpick.nl
#>
Import-Function Render-ReportField
 
filter IsRendering {
    # Look for Controller and View renderings
    $renderingIds = @("{2A3E91A0-7987-44B5-AB34-35C2D9DE83B9}","{99F8905D-4A87-4EB8-9F8B-A9BEBFB3ADD6}")
    if(($renderingIds -contains $_.TemplateID)) { $_; return }
}
 
$database = "master"
 
# Renderings Root
$renderingsRootItem = Get-Item -Path "$($database):{32566F0E-7686-45F1-A12F-D7260BD78BC3}"
$websiteRootItem = Get-Item -Path "$($database):{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}"
 
$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="websiteRootItem"; Title="Choose the report root"; Tooltip="Only items from this root will be returned."; }
    )
        Title = "Items With Component Report"
        Description = "Choose the website for the report."
        Width = 650
        Height = 250
        ShowHints = $true
        Icon = [regex]::Replace($PSScript.Appearance.Icon, "Office", "OfficeWhite", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
    }
     
    $result = Read-Variable @props
     
    if($result -eq "cancel") {
        exit
}
 
 
$items = $renderingsRootItem.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item | IsRendering
 
$reportItems = @()
foreach($item in $items) {
    $count = 0
    $websitecount = 0;
    $referrers = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $item
    if ($referrers -ne $null) {
        $count = $referrers.Count
        foreach($ref in $referrers) {
             
            if ($ref.ItemPath.StartsWith($websiteRootItem.ItemPath)) {
            $websitecount++
            }
        }
    }
 
    $reportItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Icon" = $item."__Icon"
        "Name"=$item.Name
        "UsageCount"=$count
        "WebsiteCount" = $websitecount
        "ItemPath" = $item.ItemPath
        "TemplateName" = $item.TemplateName
        "Controller" = $item.Controller
    }
    $reportItems += $reportItem
}
 
$reportProps = @{
    Property = @(
        "Icon",@{Name="Rendering Name"; Expression={$_.Name}}, 
        @{Name="Total Number of usages"; Expression={$_.UsageCount}},
        @{Name="Number of usages below: "+$websiteRootItem.Name.ToString(); Expression={$_.WebsiteCount}},
        "ItemPath",
        @{Label="Rendering Type"; Expression={$_.TemplateName} },
        "Controller"
    )
    Title = "Custom rendering report"
    InfoTitle = "Available Renderings"
    InfoDescription = "Count of references for each rendering. Results include only MVC Controller and View renderings.for" + $websiteRootItem.ItemPath.ToString()
}
 
$reportItems | 
        Sort-Object WebsiteCount -Descending |
        Show-ListView @reportProps
 
Close-Window
```

Reference and Credit : https://www.stockpick.nl/english/how-many-times-is-each-rendering-used-for-a-specific-website/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for sharng. But it seems to not work for SXA "Page Design" field where a page will be assigned a `Page Design`, which will have some `Partial Designs`, which in turn will have renderings. The code results shows that a rendering usage is 30 but it is used nowhere in any page. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this PowerShell script

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\content #this was nessesary in my case, because the original "home" item was deleted and SPE had a bug (now fixed)
$pages = get-item master:\content\MySite\articles | get-childitem -Recurse | where-object { $_.TemplateName -match "Article" }
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\MySite\ComponentsInUse.csv"
 
foreach($page in $pages){
 
    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout
 
    foreach($rendering in $renderings){
 
        if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
        {
            $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID
            if($renderingItem -ne $null)
            {
                $Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
 
                $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
            }
        }
 
    }
}
 
$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath
 
write-host 'Script ended'
```

here is a reference https://codebuildplay.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/sitecore-powershell-how-to-create-a-list-of-renderings-in-use/